# Umbraco Imagegen.ashx and keeping images in another folder

Tags: image, umbraco

I have an umbraco installation that uses imagegen.ashx.
I would like to deploy it using octopus deploy, this is pretty simpel and is already working.
My problem is that octopus deploys to a new folder (with a version number) each time, which imposes a problem with the media folder, since it can be changed in every folder.
I have made a shared folder at the same level as the versions, and I have made a virtual directory in IIS.
If I access the files directly through a browser - they exist and everything is fine.
But if I use imagegen.ashx it does not work, I have tried setting the imagebasedir property like so:

```
<Class Name="default" OverridesQueryString="true">
    <AllowUpsizing>false</AllowUpsizing>
    <MaxHeight>800</MaxHeight>
    <MaxWidth>800</MaxWidth>
    <ImageBaseDir>D:\Octopus\Applications\customer Test\customer\Shared\  </ImageBaseDir>
</Class>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in ImageGen.  Have you tried to contact Douglas Robar (http://www.percipientstudios.com/about/contact.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

**ImageBaseDir** is unlikely to expect a server mapped path.
The [imagegen documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=9326) shows examples that are either relative to the site, or from a fully-qualified url from another site.

Mapping to a path outside of your webroot will likely cause permissions issues for a number of reasons i wont get into here...though i see that you have set up the Media folder as a virtual directory. Good start, however it appears that you're mapping to the d:\ drive instead of the virtual directory you set-up (Presumably this is /Media ?).

You may also look into how the imagegen "Cached" folders are respected by your Octopus set-up. If the imagegen generated images/files get munged, that's a no-good-situation that could leave you with the appearance of missing images: 
`/(media-virtual-directory)/99999/Cached/index.xml`  could state that the generated image is @ "df1rt0lr.png" -but if that got removed in the deploy process you'll see the missing image behaviour.
Have you used the `AltImage` property to specify a fallback to a known, always available image? This will help tell if imagegen is throwing errors before outputting your expected result.
I don't believe it's an imagegen issue however, it's a pretty mature product and it's well put together as well being well documented. I would look at using a relative path for  `ImageBaseDir` - or better yet, not using this attribute at all but rather just having your /Media folder being in a constant location as your virtual directory.

Comment: I will look into this soon and accept your answer if that is the solution, thanks :-)